# Is sqlite provided with buildroot threadsafe?

Tags: buildroot

Buildroot provide a way to add sqlite to my build configuration but I can't see anywhere that it indicates if the sqlite libs have multi-thread support.  How can I tell if the version of the sqlite library included by Builtroot has multi-thread support.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "threadsafe" here?

Answer (score 5):

Buildroot's `sqlite.mk` file contains the following fragment:

```
ifeq ($(BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_THREADS),y)
SQLITE_CONF_OPTS += --enable-threadsafe
else
SQLITE_CONF_OPTS += --disable-threadsafe
SQLITE_CFLAGS += -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0
endif
```

In other words, if threads are supported, sqlite is built threadsafe.

Comment: Thank you Arnout. That's what I was looking for.